# Will there always be a pokemon on my screen?

Tags: pokemon-go

I´m out in the countryside. Will it be impossible to find a pokemon here? Do you/should you always have a pokemon "in sight" when you zoom out, or will there be areas (eg. countryside) where there will be none, forever?

Comment: From my understanding, it's based on cellular data. The busier the place, the more Pokemon there will be spawning.

Comment: Will it be *impossible*? No. But, will it be more difficult than if you were in a bigger city with more users? Yes. Living in the rural area outside of a major city, there are times where the 'nearby pokemon' box will simply be empty when I'm home.

Answer (score 12):

It is not guaranteed to have a Pokemon on your screen at all times.

Comment: You can click the "nearby Pokémon" menu in the bottom-right corner of the game's main screen to see if there are any within a quickly walkable distance.  If there aren't any, you'll either need to use incense to attract Pokémon to you or travel to somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on some server side logic. The way the game currently works is, every Pokemon is visible to every other player in that region. The Pokemon will have the same move's, size, weight and percentage level (The semi-circle behind the Pokemon in your inventory).

But there is one exception to this rule and that is incense. Once activated, you will see Pokemon occasionally spawning around you for up to 30 minute's that have a purple aura around them, just like your character, BUT other players can see them and they also don't appear in your Pokemon tracker.

Now with all that in mind, since there is 'x' amount of Pokemon spawning around any area at any time, there is a chance to collect all the Pokemon in that area even tho other players can see them since they have not collected those Pokemon themselves.

Lastly, when first logging in you might not see any Pokemon around you for a few minutes as the server did not need to create Pokemon in that area as no one was in it prior to you logging in, so you might need to move around a little bit before some Pokemon spawn.

Comment: Do you have sources for your info? I haven't seen any official information on how the game actually works.

Comment: @jackwise Most of it is actually correct. With the exception of Incense Pokemon *not* being visible to others, it's pretty spot-on.

Comment: @jackwise are you sure? I g around with a large group of people every day and never see their incense?

Comment: @0xen I didn't mean the incense, I meant the details on how spawning works, and waiting for a server to "create Pokémon in that area". While it does make sense, Niantic hasn't released details on how the game works, and with all the misinformation floating around, I'm hesitant to believe anyone but them.

Comment: @jackwise It's an assumption based on observations because there not going to generate Pokemon on their server, in every square mile, across the earth, even if no one is in that area...its just impractical